# Technical difference between Estimote beacon and Qualcomm's gimbal?

Tags: ibeacon, estimote

I have used both gimbal beacons and Estimote beacons. I need to know if there is any technical difference between the two?

Estimote costs $33 per beacon, while gimbal is merely $5!

What's the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gimbal requires you use their back-end, Estimote doesn't. Gimbal pricing is therefore tied to back-end pricing, not the cost of the beacon.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I was able to Successfully use the Gimbal beacons without using their backend. Will they permit that?

Comment: Estimote charges for their backend/cloud. Once you hit 20 beacons your cloud account will get locked until you upgrade to a paid account starting at $20/year/beacon. For me worked out to $500/year for the beacons I had in my previously free account.